# Printing first line then assign to a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    if "/xxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxx-" in a['href']:
        x = ("https://www.unkown.com" + a['href'])
        print(x[0])
    else:
        pass
        
my output:
https://www.unkown.com/xxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx
https://www.unkown.com/xxxxx/1xxxxxxxxx
https://www.unkown.com/xxxxx/2xxxxxxxxx
https://www.unkown.com/xxxxx/3xxxxxxxxx
```

I want to print the first line by doing print(x[0]) I just print "h" the output is bunch of url's

Comment: `x` is not a `tuple`, it's a string in brackets.

Comment: your `x` is a `str`, so `x[0]` will print the first character of string which is being stored in `x`. For a possible solution, what you can do is, creating an empty list and storing the matched results in that list, in this way you'll have all the URLs that contains that specific pattern. Or if you just want the first occurring URL to print and then stop loop's further execution. then on line 4 of your code, instead of using `print(x[0])`, just use `print(x)` and then on the very next line, i.e line 5 use a `break` statement to stop the execution of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your output `x` is :

```bash
https://www.unkown.com/xxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx
https://www.unkown.com/xxxxx/1xxxxxxxxx
https://www.unkown.com/xxxxx/2xxxxxxxxx
https://www.unkown.com/xxxxx/3xxxxxxxxx
```

You can access the first line by calling `x.split('\n')[0]`.

Comment: I got all the url's printed out not just one.

Comment: @Daemon, in that case, add a `\n` when you create x to get several lines: `x = ("\nhttps://www.unkown.com" + a['href'])` and after your loop remove the first line (which is empty): `x = x[1:]`.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, string indexing (x[0]) returns the character at that index, not an element from a list. In your case, x is a string, so x[0] will return 'h', the first character of your URL.

To print only the first matching URL, you can use a boolean flag. Here's an example:

```py
first_match_found = False

for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    if "/xxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxx-" in a['href'] and not first_match_found:
        print("https://www.unkown.com" + a['href'])
        first_match_found = True
```

This script will stop printing URLs after the first match.

Comment: [Generative AI (e.g. ChatGPT) is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned)